# Regex CSS Style Attribute replacements

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to selectively replace an attribute value within a CSS Style string...

The string:

```
"font-size:13pt;font-weight:600;line-height:140%;padding-top:10px;font-family:'Open Sans', 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;color:#7f1a52;padding-bottom:5px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:; text-align:center;align:center;"
```

I want to selectively replace the "center" in `text-align` and `align`, but NOT the middle in `vertical-align`.

So far I have

`string.replace(/(?<=align:)(.*?)(?=;)/g,"right")`

but that will also replace the middle in vertical align.

How can I exclude vertical-align:**middle** from being selected within this string??

Comment: you e=could check for a hyphen explicitly `/(?<=([^a-z]-+)align:)(.*?)(?=;)/g`

Comment: Are you applying this CSS to an element at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rule out only `vertical-` and capture align: in group 1. Then match the part until the semicolon that you want to replace.

In the replacement use group 1, followed by `right`

```
\b(?<!vertical-)(align:)[^;]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LBP1Tw/1)

```js
const regex = /\b(?<!vertical-)(align:)[^;]+/g;
const str = `font-size:13pt;font-weight:600;line-height:140%;padding-top:10px;font-family:'Open Sans', 'Droid Sans', Arial, sans-serif;color:#7f1a52;padding-bottom:5px;vertical-align:middle;background-color:; text-align:center;align:center;`;
const result = str.replace(regex, `$1right`);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do it with regex?

just take the element and use `Element.style.property`

So to override text-align, you can just use `Element.style.textAlign = 'other value'`